# NSInternalInconsistencyException: UITableView failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Some of my users experience a crash in

```
-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]
```

due to a **NSInternalInconsistencyException**: **UITableView failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource**.

Reading through all the answers an stackoverflow I can confirm that:

1. I connected the `UITableViewDatasource` and the `UITableViewDelegate`
2. That I registered the cell with the tableview

   `self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")`
3. That the cellForRowAtIndexPath Method is present:

   `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`
4. That every cell is initialized with

   `cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell`
5. In my opinon the returned cell cannot be nil, as I access the cell and no crash happens here

   ```
   cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
   cell.delegate = self
   cell.addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addButtonPressed(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
   cell.selectionStyle = .none
   return cell
   ```

The tableview is connected to a **realm database** with around 25.000 entries. There is a **notificationlistener**, that calls `tableview.reloadData()` once all inserts, deletions and updates have been commited. On my devices I cannot reproduce the crash.

My users now confirmed, the crash occurs when they **start typing into the searchfield**. In this case a timer starts and runs the update after 0.5 seconds.
I then filter and sort the resultset and store the reference. I then set a view as tablefooterview and call `tableview.reloadData()`

Comment: This issue is connected with the numberOfRowsInSection in tableView
The assumption can be that when your data is changing, and the array from which is the dataSource of your table view has some invalid entries. One way would be to initialize the array everytime your data is changing and adding the data into the array and then calling reloadData of the table view. Since the crash cannot be produced or there is not a real case, this is all based on assumption.

Comment: As the notificatoins are sent after the changes have been commited, the resultset has a count, that is used in `numberOfRowsInSection` I directly access this resultset in `CellForRowAtIndexPath`. Also should a wrong number of rows not result in **Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.**?